# Can I directly load bytes of a jpg file from URL into Glide?

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, byte, android-glide

One of our APIs returns bytes of a jpg file.

As I see, there are Network Libraries to download bytes,
But I just want to use Glide to download and display.

`https://subdomain.example.com:81/stack/146237.jpg`

Response Headers type

> ```
> Content-Length : 209067
> Content-Type   : image/jpg
> ```

[A Postman Screenshot of APIs responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izhih.png)

```
            val glideUrl = GlideUrl(
                "${BuildConfig.BASE_URL}/stack/146237.jpg",
                LazyHeaders.Builder()
                    .addHeader("Auth", token)
                    .build()
            )


            Glide.with(itemView.context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(glideUrl)
//                .into(object : SimpleTarget<Bitmap?>() {
//                    override fun onResourceReady(
//                        resource: Bitmap,
//                        transition: Transition<in Bitmap?>?
//                    ) {
//                        itemView.ivContactHRProfile.setImageBitmap(resource)
//                    }
//                })
                .into(object: CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
                    override fun onResourceReady(
                        resource: Bitmap,
                        transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                    ) {
                        itemView.ivContactHRProfile.setImageBitmap(resource)
                    }

                    override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

                    }

                })
```

The problem is that I don't know how to implement it with Glide.

Comment: @blackapps Please check in my [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izhih.png), that value is the binary response.

Comment: Actually, the server sends a .jpg file with `Content-Type = image/jpg` @blackapps

Comment: Its time also that you start your post telling what kind of server it is and how the url looks that you use. You are talking about content type so is it https and a webserver? (Put all info in your post!). `"${BuildConfig.BASE_URL}/stack/$loadPhoto",` We dont know where this evaluates to...